# Typescript: add instance of external dependency to window object

Tags: typescript

I am integrating an external dependency into an Enterprise project.  The integration goes like this:

```
window.foo = new Foo({
      container: `#${iframeContainerId}`,
      plugin: { id: pluginId },
    })
```

Typescript does not complain about window.foo

as I have this declaration:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    foo: any
  }
}
```

I get the error `Cannot find name 'Foo'`

Is there any way of getting Typescript to ignore this?  The external dependency is loaded using an external script and I don't think type definitions exist for it.

Comment: The keyword 'Foo' must be used somewhere within your codebase, which would be flagging up that problem

Comment: @OvidijusParsiunas The problem is occurring because I'm making a new instance of a class `Foo` but `Foo`  only exists once the script has loaded and I don't know what the type definitions are for it.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see it at the start, I have submitted an answer, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went with in the end was

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    foo: any
    Foo: any
  }
}
```

And then for the integration

```
window.foo = new window.Foo({
      container: `#${iframeContainerId}`,
      plugin: { id: pluginId },
    })
```

The solution Ovidijus Parsiunas worked but I needed to add a `.babelrc` file to the project as a result due to errors, so I went with this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your Foo class with a type as follows:

```
declare class Foo {
  constructor(obj: {
    container: string,
    plugin: { id: string },
  });
  // other methods here
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help.  I tried putting this in my `types.ts` file: 

`export declare class Foo {
  constructor(obj: { container: string; plugin: { id: string } })
}`

But when I import it with 

`import { Foo } from '../../../types'`

 I get this error in the browser console:

`export 'Foo' was not found in '../../../types'`

and a further error:

`Uncaught TypeError: _types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Foo is not a constructor`

Any ideas?

Comment: This could be a webpack setup issue. However, before we conclude that - can you try to place the ```declare class Foo ``` inside the same file where it is being used and see if that works?

Comment: If I do that I get this error: `TypeScript 'declare' fields must first be transformed by @babel/plugin-transform-typescript.
If you have already enabled that plugin (or '@babel/preset-typescript'), make sure that it runs before any plugin related to additional class features:`

Comment: Its a NextJS project

Comment: I believe the issue that you are facing now is outside the scope of the original question as it is now dependent on your setup. It would be worth raising a separate question to get it answered. Nevertheless, you could attempt to make the following config changes to see if it fixes the error you are seeing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70701279/10311008

Comment: I agree - I'll mark your answer as resolved once I figure that out.  Thanks again.